# Selecting a column whose name is a reserved SQL keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below table "sample_table"

```
id    name   desc
-------------------------
1     kkt    kkt description
1     skt    skt description
```

is there anyway I can select the third column without using its name `desc`?

Trying `select desc from mytable` throws an error

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Balan

Comment: **NO** you cannot access SQL Server columns by a numerical index.... and you shouldn't, either - the order of the columns in a relational table **is meaningless** and you shouldn't write any code that relies on that

Comment: Not without dynamic sql, and if you could it'd be a *really* bad idea. What happens when someone changes the order of columns in your table.

Comment: Ok.. i will not use this method.. Thanks for mentioning..

Comment: @Jamiec - It **is** possible without dynamics but I agree it is a bad idea.

Comment: This is why you dont try to steer the solution to a problem. If you would have stated the question as "my database uses a reserved word for a column, how do I select it" you would have gotten an answer in about a microsecond.

Comment: Yup.. i learned from this.. i should have posted my question directly...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fail to see why you need this and I would **never** use it myself.

```
declare @T table
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10),
  description varchar(25) 
)

insert into @T values
(1,     'kkt',    'kkt description'),
(1,     'skt',    'skt description')

select T2.N.value('*[3]', 'varchar(max)')
from (select *
      from @T
      for xml path('r'), type) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('/r') as T2(N)
```

**Update**

You should do like this instead.

```
select [desc]
from YourTable
```

Use `[]` around column names that is reserved words.

Comment: because in my client's database they have used a field named "desc" for description.. but when i use `select desc from mytable' it throws an error.. thats why i am trying to access the column through index..

Comment: @balanv - You should use `[]` around column names that is reserved words. Updated answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use standard SQL quoted identifiers around column names that are reserved words e.g.

```
SELECT "desc" FROM sample_table;
```

Comment: `\`desc\`` works but `"desc"` didn't work for me. You can make an addition to your answer`.

Comment: @VikasGautam: yours it not Standard SQL then. MySQL?

Comment: @onedaywhen thanks for your answer. Using `" "` works even for columns which have space in definition. `select "team manager" from x`

Answer (score 1):

select mytable.desc from mytable;

work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
Declare @WhichOne int;
Declare @Sql varchar(200);
SET @WhichOne = 2;
WITH cte AS
(SELECT name, Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY column_id) AS rn
FROM sys.COLUMNS
WHERE Object_Name(object_id) = 'MyTable')
SELECT @Sql = 'Select ' + QuoteName(name) + ' From MyTable'
FROM cte
WHERE rn = @WhichOne;
Exec(@Sql);
```

From http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/ms-sql/threads/341388

Answer (score 0):

Just so you can go shoot yourself in the foot, here's how you could do it with dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
select 
    @sql = 'SELECT ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' FROM YourTable'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='YourTable' 
AND ORDINAL_POSITION=3
exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```