# How to use .Locate when column name is a keyword

Tags: delphi, ado

Using XE5 and ADO, how can I use `TADOQuery.Locate` when the column name is a key word?

For example, we have a table that has a column named `Desc`, which is a keyword.

The code below generates runtime error (exception class `EOleException` with message `Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another`):

```
ADOQueryQP1.Locate('Desc', 'FindMe', [])
```

I've tried [] and double quotes around `Desc`.

With `[Desc]` or `"Desc"` (single or double quotes), we get exception class `EDatabaseError` with message `ADOQueryQP1: Field '[Desc]' not found`.

Related question from someone else in 2012: [Selecting a column whose name is a reserved SQL keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633449/selecting-a-column-whose-name-is-a-reserved-sql-keyword)

Comment: Have you tried `'[Desc]'`?

Comment: Thanks, TOndrej. But [Desc] fails with the message

... exception class EDatabaseError with message 'ADOQueryQP1: Field '[Desc]' not found'.

Comment: do you have the source code for TADOQuery?

Comment: I think @TOndrej meant AdoQuery.Locate('[Desc]', 'FindMe', []).  Is that what you tred?

Comment: @mjn Yes, we have the source to TADOQuery.  Not sure we want to modify it, but what would you suggest?

Comment: I cant reproduce with sql server 2005. Locate ('Desc') works fine. What run time error are you getting?

Comment: With a debugger and the source code you can see the final SQL statement that is going to be sent to the SQL server, so you can verify that the field is enclosed in the correct delimiters (brackets or quotes).

Comment: #kobik - without any [] or '', we get 

exception class EOleException with message 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

With [Desc] or "Desc" (single or double quotes), we get 

exception class EDatabaseError with message 'ADOQueryQP1: Field '[Desc]' not found'.

Comment: Have you tried QuotedStr('Desc') in effect '''Desc''' I think that's how I got around the level keyword

Comment: Did you consider adding an alias to your field? `select [desc] as description from yourtable`. You could use `if ADOQueryQP1.Locate('description', 'blah', []) then`

Answer (score 1):

See if the following workaround is acceptable for you:

1. Set the ADOConnection's `Provider` property to `'SQLOLEDB'`, and
2. Set the ADOQuery's `CursorLocation` property to `clUseServer`.